# Multi table sql query

Tags: sql

I need to create a query with multiple tables for a project for school, but I'm not really good at this.

I've got 2 tables.

The first is a table with trajects:

```
departure_time (time)
arrival_time (time)
departure_id (int)
arrival_id (int)
```

The second table holds the names of the locations:

```
location_id (int)
name (varchar)
```

I would need a query that gets the `departure_time`, `arrival_time` and the names of the `departure place` and the `arrival place`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an inner join;

```
select
  departure_time,
  arrival_time,
  depart.name,
  arrive.name
from trajects 
  inner join locations depart on (depart.location_id = trajects.departure_id)
  inner join locations arrive on (arrive.location_id = trajects.arrival_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  t.departure_time, 
  t.arrival_time, 
  d.name as 'DeparturePlace', 
  a.name as 'ArrivalPlace'
FROM 
  Trajects t, Locations d, Locations a 
WHERE 
  t.departure_id = d.location_id AND 
  t.arrival_id = a.location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need to do is an SQL JOIN on the departure_id and the arrival_id onto the second table. Details and examples [here](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp).

Comment: Thank you, but the trouble is that i need 1 row from the first table and two rows from the second table.

Comment: A join like the one I'm describing would be able to achieve this. Didn't just want to write a quer for you as this sounds homeworky.

Comment: Don't worry, the project is much bigger than this.